# How to parse JSON array in array Swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, codable, decodable

I'm trying to parse JSON which is like below:

```
"price": [
            [
                1539283140000,
                6288.07
            ],
            [
                1539283440000,
                6285.82
            ],
            [
                1539283740000,
                6285.81
            ],
            [
                1539284041000,
                6280.37
            ],
            [
                1539284340000,
                6280.19
            ]
```

Please help me deal with this. And is there a possibility to decode the timestamp value to a date.

Comment: You surely tried *something*. Don't hesitate to show your attempt, so that this does not look like a “write the code for me” question!

Comment: And for what it is worth: you are not even showing us valid Json..

Answer (score 0):

Correct json

```
{
    "price": [
            [
                1539283140000,
                6288.07
            ],
            [
                1539283440000,
                6285.82
            ],
            [
                1539283740000,
                6285.81
            ],
            [
                1539284041000,
                6280.37
            ],
            [
                1539284340000,
                6280.19
            ]
         ]
}
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
    let price: [[Double]]
}
```

---

```
let res = try? JSONDecodable().decode(Root.self,from:jsonData)
```

Comment: Don't encourage such low quality questions. Not every question should be answered.